# LEFT JOIN in 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, aggregate-functions

Why doesn't this query execute correctly?

```
SELECT pr.ProjectNumber,
    SUM(ma.TotalAmount) As CostOfMaterials,
    SUM(ot.TotalAmount) AS CostOfOthers
FROM [dbo].[tblProject] AS pr
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblCostOfMaterials] AS ma ON pr.ProjectNumber=ma.ProjectNumber
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblCostOfOthers] AS ot ON pr.ProjectNumber=ot.ProjectNumber
GROUP BY pr.ProjectNumber
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what does the error say? If you just don't get the result you desire what do you wish to achieve and what does this give you? We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: Why this question is not done correctly?  Without some sort of error message it is hard to help.

Comment: Is that homework of some kind or interview question? I see big design problem, but depend on circumstances answer can be different.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that because each table has multiple rows for a particular project number you count the same values multiple times. To avoid this you can use

```
;WITH ma
     AS (select ProjectNumber,
                SUM(TotalAmount) as CostOfMaterials
         FROM   [dbo].[tblCostOfMaterials]
         GROUP  BY ProjectNumber),
     ot
     AS (select ProjectNumber,
                SUM(TotalAmount) as CostOfOthers
         FROM   [dbo].[tblCostOfOthers]
         GROUP  BY ProjectNumber)
SELECT pr.ProjectNumber, 
       CostOfMaterials, 
       CostOfOthers
FROM   [dbo].[tblProject] AS pr
       LEFT JOIN ma
         ON pr.ProjectNumber = ma.ProjectNumber
       LEFT JOIN ot
         ON pr.ProjectNumber = ot.ProjectNumber
```

The reason why you get that behaviour is because you are getting mini Cartesian joins

```
WITH tblProject (ProjectNumber) AS
(
SELECT 1
),tblCostOfMaterials(ProjectNumber, TotalAmount) AS
(
SELECT 1,101 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,201 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,301 
),
tblCostOfOthers(ProjectNumber, TotalAmount) AS
(
SELECT 1,100 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,200 
)
SELECT *
FROM [tblProject] AS pr
LEFT JOIN [tblCostOfMaterials] AS ma ON pr.ProjectNumber=ma.ProjectNumber
LEFT JOIN [tblCostOfOthers] AS ot ON pr.ProjectNumber=ot.ProjectNumber
```

Returns

```
ProjectNumber ProjectNumber TotalAmount ProjectNumber TotalAmount
------------- ------------- ----------- ------------- -----------
1             1             101         1             100
1             1             101         1             200
1             1             201         1             100
1             1             201         1             200
1             1             301         1             100
1             1             301         1             200
```

You can see that the values are duplicated by the number of matching rows in the other table so the `SUM` will be incorrect.